# Use tableviewcell from different function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a likebutton on my TableViewCell on which I added a target. The target executes a function to send a like to the API.

```
//inside cellForRowAt
cell.likeMessage.tag = indexPath.row
cell.likeMessage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLikes), for:.touchUpInside)

//in viewcontroller class 
func handleLikes(_sender: UIButton){ 
    let index = cell.tag
    Alamofire.request("url")
}
```

Now I would like to set `likeMessage.isEnabled = false` after the request in handleLikes. 
What's the best way of doing that since I can't call the cell.

Solution

I already had the solution. I can just call:

```
 _sender.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: pass your likeMessage button as argument to handleLikes function.

Comment: @UmairAfzal Oh s**t, this was so obvious. Sorry for even asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can like / dislike the message.
if your button is enabled, it will make the api request. In case your button is disabled it will make the button enabled.

```
    cell.likeMessage.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.likeMessage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLikes(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

    func handleLikes(_sender: UIButton){
        if(_sender.isEnabled){
            _sender.isEnabled = false
            Alamofire.request("url")
        }else{
            _sender.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

if you want to retrieve the cell in the function you can pass the indexPath.row as an argument and retrieve the cell in the function.

```
func handleLikes(row: Int){
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
        let cell = self.yourTableViewName.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! YourTableCell
        //here you will have the cell and you can use it as you like
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to send both buttons as arguments in the selector?

Comment: @Fabioha, one easy way is to send the indexPath.row as an argument in the selector. then in the function you can get the whole cell through the indexpath.

Comment: That would probably be easier, so how would i use the cell in the function then?

Comment: @Fabioha i have edited the answer, you can retrieve the whole cell this way and do the required operation on the cell.

Comment: Ok, It worked like that also made a lot more sense for me.

Comment: @Fabioha, can you also accept it as the correct answer if it solved the problem :) thanks

Comment: Is it possible to pass parameters with the selector?

Comment: can you give an example what would you like to pass?

Comment: Just for example a String, I always get the error that it doesn't conform to the protocol

Comment: you will have to update the function as well that it can receive multiple arguments. I haven't tested the code but it will be something like this

`func handlingMultipleValues(val1: Int, withAnotherVal val2: Int) {
    print(val1)
    print(val2)
}
addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlingMultipleValues(_: withAnotherVal:))`

Answer (score 1):

Pass your button in target:

```
    cell.likeMessage.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.likeMessage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLikes(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

    //in viewcontroller class 
    func handleLikes(_sender: UIButton){ 
 _sender.isEnabled = false
        let index = cell.tag
        Alamofire.request("url")
    }
```

Comment: If I also have a dislikeButton and a handleDislike. How could I enable the likeButton again if the dislike is clicked?

Comment: you can pass your whole cell to the function and check if the button in the cell is selected on un selected. also in that function if the button is selected then you don't need to fire the api request. and if it un selected you make the button selected and fire the api request.

Comment: You have instance of like button, when dislike button clicked called this likeMessage.isEnabled = true @Fabioha

Comment: @SaurabhJain Not really, what do you mean with instance, because I can't call likeMessage Button form dislike function.

Comment: instance means, outlet of your likeMessage button, When you click on dislike button then called this likeMessage.isEnabled = true , Got it? @Fabioha

Answer (score 0):

If the table does not contain a section, you can try to refresh the cell in tableview.

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`
2. use `cellForIndexPath`
3. passing UIButton reference to selector then update in callback closure.

If you want to add animation effect on likeButton, try second or third. :D